# How to track Created Invite links (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

*Hi I need help*

I am currently working on a bot that makes an action whenever somebody creates a number of invite links in a server. but I have no idea how to access the created invite links and it creates

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `on_invite_create` event.

```
@bot.event
async def on_invite_create(invite):
    print(f"Invite has been created. Its url is {invite.url}.")
```

To fetch all guild's invites you can use something like this:

```py
for invite in await guild.invites():
    print(invite.url)
```

#### References

[`on_invite_create` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_invite_create)
[`invites()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.invites)
[`Invite` class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#invite)

Comment: thanks that is very useful. It solved my problem

Comment: Then, could you accept my answer, please. (Use a green tick near it)